# NSString - rangeOfString method that ignore previous occurence of string

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

From the docs, I realize that every rangeOfString method & its variants finds the 1st occurrence in a string. So If I have a string of "I can have I or not", it will never catch the 2nd instance of "I". I could use the NSBackwardsSearch operator but it will find the last but not the 1st.

What I am trying to do is using a Stepper in my View to underline every word in a sentence sequentially. But the problem arises when it finds the same word it has encountered before for it will underline the 1st occurrence of that word instead of the 2nd occurrence where the current location is.

Any suggestion on how to ignore previous occurrence of a string using rangeOfString? Or is there another method I can accomplish this with?

-Yohannes

Comment: A 5 second scan of the documentation would have revealed the other forms of the `rangeOfString...` method. Always check the docs first.

Answer (score 3):

Use one of the `-rangeOfString:options:range:...` methods, passing the range after what you've already found.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"I can have I or not";

NSUInteger count = 0, length = [str length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);
while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    range = [str rangeOfString: @"I" options:0 range:range];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
        NSLog(@"found %@",NSStringFromRange(range));
        count++; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if you just use substrings, then you will also match substrings that are a part of other words, for instance the "is" in "arises" in your second paragraph. From your description that is not what you want, but I may have misread it.

Core Foundation provides `CFStringTokenizer` which helps do these things across different locales.

The code below is not optimised in any way:

```
NSString *para = @"What I am trying to do is using a Stepper in my View to underline every word in a sentence sequentially. But the problem arises when it finds the same word it has encountered before for it will underline the 1st occurrence of that word instead of the 2nd occurrence where the current location is.";

NSString *searchedWord = @"is";

NSUInteger selectedOccurrence = 2;  // From your stepper, zero-based.
NSUInteger counter            = NSNotFound;
NSRange    selectedRange      = NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0);

CFStringTokenizerRef tokenizer = CFStringTokenizerCreate (NULL,(CFStringRef)para,CFRangeMake(0, para.length),kCFStringTokenizerUnitWord,NULL);

CFStringTokenizerTokenType tokenType;


while ( (tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer)) != kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone ) {

    CFRange tokenRange = CFStringTokenizerGetCurrentTokenRange(tokenizer);

    NSString *token = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)CFStringCreateWithSubstring(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)para, tokenRange);

    if ( [token compare:searchedWord options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch] == NSOrderedSame ) {

        // An occurrence of the word is found!

        counter = counter == NSNotFound ? 0 : counter + 1;

        if ( counter == selectedOccurrence ) {

            // We found the occurrence we were looking for

            selectedRange = NSMakeRange(tokenRange.location, tokenRange.length);

            break;
        }
    }
};

// If selectedRange is different from the initial {NSNotFound,0} then we found something
if ( ! NSEqualRanges(selectedRange, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0)) ) {
    // Highlight your word found at selectedRange
    NSLog(@"Found at %@", NSStringFromRange(selectedRange));
}
else {
    // Not found, clean up
    NSLog(@"An occurence number %ld not found", selectedOccurrence);
}
```

Comment: You should be able to achieve this same thing with NSString's `enumerateSubstringsInRange:`.  Something like: `[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) options:NSStringEnumerationByWords | NSStringEnumerationLocalized usingBlock:...]`